# Cannot Cancel Auto Renew

Tags: wordpress, auto-renew

WordPress v6.1.1 | CiviCRM v 5.59.2

When I attempt to cancel auto renew for Members, it gives me Error: Required information missing in a pop up box on the upper right. There is no more info in the box.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Still trying to get this fixed. WordPress v6.4.2  CiviCRM v5.58.0

Comment: WordPress v6.4.3 CiviCRM v5.69.2 Still a problem. Here are the images and error message: https://imgur.com/a/F2WugwY

Comment: It may help folk help you if you mention what Payment Processor you are using

Comment: Using regular Paypal account.

Comment: So, maybe none of it is operating. You can see from the Membership Page Auto Renew is greyed out, but some areas have the slash zero and the others are blank. Is there simply somewhere in sql I can go and delete all of the autorenewals? Still an issue as I can't use the feature to cancel. Screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/vB7D3FLhttps://imgur.com/a/vB7D3FL